# how can i set a alert when wrong username or password authentication on ASI Http Request?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, asihttprequest

for me i have done asi http request .but when i call this methode on login page.how can i set authentication alert view for false login the method of ASI HTTP Request is below

```
-(void) authenticate:(NSString*) uname password:(NSString*) pwd{

NSString *format = @"%s %d";
NSLog(format, __FUNCTION__);

myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)   [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
appDelegate.HUD.progress = 0.1f;
appDelegate.HUD.labelText =  @"Authenticating...";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/login",appDelegate.appData.server]];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.shouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge = YES;
[request addBasicAuthenticationHeaderWithUsername:uname andPassword:pwd];


[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(authenticationFailed:)];

request.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"authenticate" forKey:@"type"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];}
```

Comment: and i used for alert in failed method-(IBAction)authenticationFailed
{NSString *format = @"%s %d";
    NSLog(format, __FUNCTION__);
    warningAlert =[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication Failed" message:@"Username Or Password doesn't Exit" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [warningAlert show];
}

Answer (score 4):

```
- (IBAction)login_btn:(id)sender {
//    secondview *second=[[secondview alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:nil];
//    [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
//    [second release];

/*
 triangletechniqa.com/projects/funny/webservic/login.php?username=admin&password=123

 */
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",uesrname_text.text,password_text.text];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itriangletechniqa.com/projects/funny/webservic/login.php?"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
// NSMutableArray *tempArr = [str JSONValue];
// NSLog(@"%@",tempArr);


if([str isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
    UIAlertView *unsucess=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorrrrry" message:@"Incurrect username and password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [unsucess show];
    [unsucess release];
}

else
{
    UIAlertView *success = [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"successful" message:@"angry"
                                                     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];


    [success show];
            secondview *view=[[secondview alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
    [view release];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite catch you. 
Are you find the right position to put your alertview code?

I have some experience in using asihttprequest, but I haven't use

`addBasicAuthenticationHeaderWithUsername:`

method.

Instead, I use `setpostvalue` method to post user account and password. If they are in a same way, you can add another callback method just like

```
[request setDidSuccessSelector:@selector(resultProgress:)];
```

In `resultProgress:` method, you can check the result from server.

If it's false login, you can show a alertview.